# Using `flatMap().filter().map()` together on a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I use following method to find `identifier` where `isBoolTrue==true` from a nested array (screenshot of array and data structure below)

```
func extractIdentifiers(mainArray: [MainItem]) -> [Int]? {
    var selected = [Int]()
    mainArray.forEach { element in
        let integers = element.innerArray?.filter({ $0.isBoolTrue }).map {
            Int($0.identifier)!
        }
        if !(integers?.isEmpty ?? true) {
            selected += integers!
        }
    }

    return selected.isEmpty ? nil : selected
}
```

**Question:** is that possible to use some sort of chaining `flatMap().filter().map()` to produce the same result `[Int]?`, so that I will be able to eliminate the use of `mainArray.forEach` and those conditional checks `selected.isEmpty` and `integers?.isEmpty`?

**NOTE:** I need help within above method `extractIdentifiers`, below you will find data and structure to play around, also a screenshot of array.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

**Structure & Data:**

```
struct InnerItem {
    let identifier: String
    var isBoolTrue: Bool
}
struct MainItem {
    var innerArray: [InnerItem]?
}
let str = "[{\"innerArray\":[{\"identifier\":\"0\",\"isBoolTrue\":true},{\"identifier\":\"1\",\"isBoolTrue\":false}]},{\"innerArray\":[{\"identifier\":\"3\",\"isBoolTrue\":true},{\"identifier\":\"4\",\"isBoolTrue\":false}]},{\"innerArray\":null}]"

let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String : Any]]
var mainArray = [MainItem]()
json!.forEach { dict in
    if let array = dict["innerArray"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        let innerArray = array.map {
            InnerItem(identifier: $0["identifier"] as! String, isBoolTrue: $0["isBoolTrue"] as! Bool)
        }
        mainArray.append(MainItem(innerArray: innerArray))
    }
}
```

**Tests & Output**

```
var selected: [Int]? // FILL THIS ARRAY WITH `identifier`

// Test1
selected = extractIdentifiers(mainArray: mainArray) // OUTPUT: [0, 3]

// Test2
mainArray[0].innerArray![0].isBoolTrue = false
selected = extractIdentifiers(mainArray: mainArray) // OUTPUT: [3]

// Test3
mainArray[1].innerArray![0].isBoolTrue = false
selected = extractIdentifiers(mainArray: mainArray) // OUTPUT: nil
```

Comment: @Alexander I will post data structure in a while, sorry for delay, babysitting now

Answer (score 3):

My approach is flatten the nested array into an array of dictionaries using double `flatMap`, then filter those object with `true` value and at last use map to get the "identifier" value.

```
let result = data.flatMap { $0.flatMap { $0.value } } // this line will flatten into one level
        .filter { $0["isBoolTrue"] == true }
        .map { $0["identifier"] }

print(result) // this will output ["0", "3"]
```

Note: To have better understanding on the output, try print line by line

Comment: Thanks for your response, although this is almost like what I wanted, but I am still having difficulties using it :) I have `innerArray` in my JSON, which I do not see in your answer (check my screenshot).
Please have a look at the data and structure that I just provided, would you be able to use your lines within `extractIdentifiers ` method

Comment: @AamirR yep, you wont see the "innerArray" key because we collapse it twice using double `flatmap()`. So two layers are removed. You can try use one by one `flatmap` to understand the result